# using logfile and displaying results and activity to console in ant

Tags: ant

I am currently using the `-logfile` flag on my ant script. Is there a way to display the ant output to the console and have it log the output too?

I can not download other applications to acheive this. Needs to be native to windows or ant.

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595538/getting-ant-to-log-to-file-as-well-as-screen-terminal

Comment: @martinclayton: Very good. Thank you. I will look into this further.

Comment: @martinclayton: this actually appears to be what i am looking for, is there any chance that you can post this as an answer so that i can accept it and give you your points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant has a [recorder task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) that can be used to log all or part of a build to a file.

To just record the whole build to a file add a line like:

```
<record name="build.log" />
```

near to the start of your buildfile.  There are options to set the level of verbosity and control log file appending too.

You can run multiple recorders during a build - say to capture a summary to one log file, and full details to a longer second log file.  You can also use the `action` attribute of the task to run the recording for just part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

With "native to Windows", do you mean that it must run on Windows?

If so, you can use the **tee** command:

```
ant | tee logfile.txt
```

will show the output on the console and log it in `logfile.txt` at the same time.

*tee* is originally a unix command. On windows, you can get it as part of the free [Unix Utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: "I can not download other applications to acheive this."